# Improving fuzzy PNG image used as company logo in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, png

Why is my company Logo in the title block of my ArcGIS map blurry?  The logo was inserted into the title block as a PNG image and appears blurry when I export the map to PDF.

Comment: Can you include your logo image and screenshot of what it looks like in your PDF?  Is it resized up or down in your layout?

Comment: It depends on several things in combination: pixel dimensions of the PNG, the size you make the PNG inside the map layout, the DPI setting you make the export.  Ideally, you should only ever shrink a PNG inside the map layout, never enlarge it. Then make sure your DPI is set high enough so it doesn't "pixelate" your PNG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For best logo results, make sure you start with a PNG that has high pixel values, like 3500x3500 (if it's a square).

Next, make sure you shrink that down to at most a couple inches.

For export settings, set DPI to 600, and Image Compression to "LZW".

Then export to PDF.